# create-react-app Won't Deploy to Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, create-react-app

In March I successfully created a create-react-app and deployed it to Google Cloud Platform following this article [Medium - Deploying a React App to GCP](https://medium.com/better-programming/deploy-a-react-app-to-google-cloud-platform-using-google-app-engine-3f74fbd537ec). I have been trying again since yesterday to deploy a project, however I continuously get this error

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.           
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED
yarn run v1.17.3
$ react-scripts start
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.7/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Done in 2.61s.
```

I am not doing anything differently, I am even trying to deploy a vanilla create-react-app to rule out my own error. I cannot figure out why it is doing this. The only thing I have noticed, is it is trying to deploy to **https://myprojecturl.uk.r.appspot.com/** instead of **https://myprojecturl.appspot.com/** even though I am choosing us-east-4 region. Is this of any relevance?

In the logs there also does not appear to be any significant errors--the only thing I see is an *App Unhealthy* error

```
A 2020-04-09T21:51:53.359Z GET 503 18 B 0 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /liveness_check GET 503 18 B 0 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A 2020-04-09T21:51:57.524899959Z Unhealthy sidecars detected: gaeapp 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:01.887058019Z Health checks: instance=aef-default-20200409t174222-nfc3 start=2020-04-09T21:49:23+00:00 end=2020-04-09T21:49:54+00:00 total=6 unhealthy=0 healthy=6 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:09.142Z GET 503 18 B 0 ms curl/7.64.1 /liveness_check GET 503 18 B 0 ms curl/7.64.1 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:09.417176008Z ------------------------VM aef-default-20200409t174222-nfc3 shutdown initiated----------------------- 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:09.417176009Z Current app health: 0 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:09.446892Z stackdriver-monitoring-agent 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:10.076719045Z Beginning service lameduck. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.293428897Z Triggering app shutdown handlers. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.293428898Z Apr 09 21:52:35 Pure compute version. Should skip _ah/start or stop. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.293428899Z <13>Apr  9 21:52:35 vm_runtime_init: Apr 09 21:52:35 Pure compute version. Should skip _ah/start or stop. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.293428900Z Sending SIGTERM to app. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.293428901Z Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: bbd700fb530efb86c5b5d833b760edfeb284e4044d5762f3204f82dba5b57bc8: Container bbd700fb530efb86c5b5d833b760edfeb284e4044d5762f3204f82dba5b57bc8 is not running 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.293428902Z Sending SIGKILL to app. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.293428903Z Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: bbd700fb530efb86c5b5d833b760edfeb284e4044d5762f3204f82dba5b57bc8: Container bbd700fb530efb86c5b5d833b760edfeb284e4044d5762f3204f82dba5b57bc8 is not running 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.293428904Z App shutdown handlers done. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059909Z --------------App was unhealthy, grabbing debug logs--------------- 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059910Z -------------------------App stdout/stderr------------------------- 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059911Z yarn run v1.17.3 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059912Z $ react-scripts start 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059913Z [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Project is running at http://172.17.0.7/ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059914Z [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from  
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059915Z [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059916Z [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: 404s will fallback to / 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059917Z Starting the development server... 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059918Z {"textPayload":"","insertId":"45uibhfbtt4so","resource":{"type":"gae_app","labels":{"project_id":"abstract-key-273721","version_id":"20200409t174222","module_id":"default","zone":""}},"timestamp":"2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059918Z","labels":{"appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name":"aef-default-2020040… 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059919Z Done in 2.61s. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059920Z ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059921Z -------------------------Tail of app logs-------------------------- 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059922Z App logs not found. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059923Z ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059924Z -------------------------Additional debug info-------------------------- 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059925Z cat: /home/vmagent/abstract-key-273721_20200409t174222-425864491634899607.env: No such file or directory 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059926Z Instance has machine type of custom-2-5632 has 2 vCPU and 5632 Mb memory. App can use  Mb memory. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059927Z VM memory consumption: 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059928Z               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059929Z Mem:           5461         464        3142           0        1854        4707 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059930Z Swap:             0           0           0 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059931Z VM disk usage: 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059932Z Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059933Z /dev/root      ext2       1249792  749884    499908  61% / 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059934Z devtmpfs       devtmpfs   2793344       0   2793344   0% /dev 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059935Z overlayfs      overlay    2796056     200   2795856   1% /etc 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059936Z /dev/sda8      ext4         11760      28     11408   1% /usr/share/oem 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059937Z /dev/sda1      ext4      16293736 2718096  13559256  17% /mnt/stateful_partition 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059938Z overlay        overlay   16293736 2718096  13559256  17% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0b7a17b1e7f9d6eabbb7f445b6ea9ce21498d30bf8f886bd296c3f2172d3e47a/merged 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059939Z overlay        overlay   16293736 2718096  13559256  17% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/6a519b66fd2a0950f74991b29ca6e400700f2685aa8bec86677e9788b8dece0b/merged 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059940Z overlay        overlay   16293736 2718096  13559256  17% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/98049d447d16354007c7aa59be083b30a773526f643b177ad9e46f2a7460d4f4/merged 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059941Z overlay        overlay   16293736 2718096  13559256  17% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/11c6e93a4a2c67a4f9d590a6925fe1fd2ddbdb34b4c9623196ea16881b8bf1ab/merged 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059942Z Processes running on the VM: 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059943Z top - 21:52:35 up 4 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.20, 0.55, 0.28 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059944Z Tasks:  91 total,   1 running,  90 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059945Z %Cpu(s): 20.0 us,  3.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 76.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059946Z MiB Mem :   5461.1 total,   3135.5 free,    470.7 used,   1854.9 buff/cache 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059947Z MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   4701.4 avail Mem  
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059948Z {"textPayload":"","insertId":"45uibhfbtt4ti","resource":{"type":"gae_app","labels":{"version_id":"20200409t174222","module_id":"default","zone":"","project_id":"abstract-key-273721"}},"timestamp":"2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059948Z","labels":{"compute.googleapis.com/resource_id":"9018279946096879309","c… 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059949Z     PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059950Z    6418 root      20   0   41536  24968   7572 S  40.0   0.4   0:00.16 python2+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059951Z       1 root      20   0   99880   7616   5280 S   0.0   0.1   0:03.55 systemd 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059952Z       2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059953Z       3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059954Z       4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059955Z       5 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.11 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059956Z       6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059957Z       7 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.88 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059958Z       8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_perc+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059959Z       9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.04 ksoftir+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059960Z      10 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.26 rcu_sch+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059961Z      11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059962Z      12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 migrati+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059963Z      13 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059964Z      14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059965Z      15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059966Z      16 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.42 migrati+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059967Z      17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 ksoftir+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059968Z      18 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059969Z      19 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059970Z      20 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmp+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059971Z      21 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 netns 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059972Z      22 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kauditd 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059973Z      23 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.07 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059974Z      24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 khungta+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059975Z      25 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 oom_rea+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059976Z      26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 writeba+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059977Z      27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kcompac+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059978Z      28 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 khugepa+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059979Z      29 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 crypto 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059980Z      30 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kintegr+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059981Z      31 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kblockd 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059982Z      32 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059983Z      33 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 md 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059984Z      34 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 watchdo+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059985Z      35 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kswapd0 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059986Z      55 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthrotld 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059987Z      56 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 acpi_th+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059988Z      57 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 hwrng 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059989Z      58 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059990Z      59 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tm+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059991Z      60 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.54 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059992Z      61 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059993Z      62 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.09 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059994Z      63 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 dm_bufi+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059995Z      64 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:01.25 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059996Z      65 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ipv6_ad+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059997Z      70 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059998Z      71 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kverityd 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805059999Z      72 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ext4-rs+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060Z     102 root      20   0   29512  10540   9744 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.55 systemd+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060001Z     104 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060002Z     106 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.44 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060003Z     107 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060004Z     119 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.10 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060005Z     120 root      20   0   16040   5176   4208 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.14 systemd+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060006Z     174 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 jbd2/sd+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060007Z     175 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ext4-rs+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060008Z     179 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.67 jbd2/sd+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060009Z     180 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ext4-rs+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060010Z     201 systemd+  20   0   91944   4572   4092 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.04 systemd+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060011Z     202 systemd+  20   0   23552   4732   4172 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.07 systemd+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060012Z     216 systemd+  20   0   18532   4156   3740 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.11 systemd+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060013Z     303 root      20   0 1257972  35080  14612 S   0.0   0.6   0:00.39 contain+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060014Z     309 root      20   0 1220420 120000  28160 S   0.0   2.1   0:31.11 dockerd 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060015Z     396 root      20   0   34788  19168   6616 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.24 google_+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060016Z     567 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.77 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060017Z     891 root      20   0    9540   3248   2844 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 bash 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060018Z    1045 root      20   0  764116  48480  22500 S   0.0   0.9   0:00.07 docker 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060019Z    1106 root      20   0  107444   5836   4816 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.02 contain+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060020Z    1146 root      20   0  253056  64900   9792 S   0.0   1.2   0:02.52 google-+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060021Z    1321 root      20   0  108852   5336   4384 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.01 contain+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060022Z    1341 root      20   0   46156  14384   6956 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.22 iap_wat+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060023Z    1506 root      20   0  108852   4820   3900 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.03 contain+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060024Z    1523 root      20   0   17976   2836   2536 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.05 start_n+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060025Z    1546 root      20   0   27996   2160   1924 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cron 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060026Z    1682 root      20   0   27996   2180   1948 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cron 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060027Z    1686 root      20   0   41124  12028   8392 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.05 nginx 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060028Z    1687 101       20   0   42968   6936   1428 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 nginx 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060029Z    1688 101       20   0   42968   6936   1428 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.05 nginx 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060030Z    1803 root      20   0  444212  97824  11904 S   0.0   1.7   0:06.97 ruby 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060031Z    3180 root      20   0  107444   5480   4820 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.01 contain+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060032Z    3198 root      20   0    8144   3728   3116 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.04 proxy 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060033Z    4502 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060034Z    6263 root      20   0   35052  19264   6468 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.18 google_+ 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060035Z    6271 root      20   0    9408   3056   2804 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 bash 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060036Z    6276 root      20   0    9408   2992   2744 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 bash 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060037Z    6277 root      20   0    9672   3404   2928 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 bash 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060038Z    6415 root      20   0    9672   2180   1680 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 bash 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060039Z    6416 root      20   0    9672   1900   1424 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 bash 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060040Z    6446 root      20   0   11340   2420   2236 R   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 top 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060041Z Additional thread and heap info may be available in app.shutdown if you are using a supported client library. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060042Z ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060043Z Sending SIGUSR1 to fluentd to trigger a log flush. 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060044Z 2839607a85eed37bf383857d62abc881631687a5b55c7ffad8322e1633189335 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:35.805060045Z ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:36.001706Z 2020-04-09 21:52:36 +0000 [info]: #0 force flushing buffered events 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:36.002713Z 2020-04-09 21:52:36 +0000 [info]: #0 flushing all buffer forcedly 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:36.308702Z 2020-04-09 21:52:36 +0000 [info]: Received graceful stop 
A 2020-04-09T21:52:37.086883Z 2020-04-09 21:52:37 +0000 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now stopping worker=0
```

I just copied and pasted some of the log output because I am not sure what would be needed to debug this. Let me know if there is anything else that would help me figure out why this wouldn't work as expected despite the same approach and execution.

Comment: It's not much, but this might be some clue for you. When I tried to deploy the same app on my existing project with old app I faced the same issue. I tried on completely new project and again the same. However when I removed resources part from app.yaml it deployed successfully. But it's working only on this new project... On the old one its not working even with changed yaml... Unfortunately I cannot continue research now, if you do not figure it out I can continue next week. Good Luck!

Comment: I ended up just taking a few hours and learned Docker and Kubernetes to deploy it on Kubernetes Engine. Thank you for the tips though! @vitooh